# VUE3 - Select element on mounted() or created() in a custom component without using "event"

Tags: vuejs3

i have a custom input component and i want to select it without clicking on it or something so i cant use "event", i want to select it on created() or mounted()

how can i do that?

```js
<template>
  

    <div class="form-control">
        <label :for="id">
          {{ label }}
        </label>
        <input
          :id="id"
          :type="mode"
          :value="currentValue"
          @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
          @focus="pullLabel"
          @blur="pushLabel"
        />
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {       
    
      created() {
        this.test();
      },     
      
    
      methods: {
        
        test() {
          console.log(this); // -> How could this be like '<input id="title" type="text">'
        },

      },

    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself after 6~ hours of work.

The answer is `$refs`

I sent a "ref" from parent component like this:

```
<form ref="settingsForm" @submit.prevent="updateConfig">
```

Then in `methods`, i selected all the inputs in form like this: (except submit input)

```js
methods: {
...

focusInput() {
  const inputs = this.$refs.settingsForm.querySelectorAll(
    'input:not([type="submit"])'
  ); // $refs.settingsForm -> comes from the parent element, you can name "settingsForm" whatever you want

  Array.from(inputs).map((e) => {
    if (e.value.length > 0) {
      e.previousElementSibling.classList.add("clicked-input");
    }
  });
},
    
...  
}
```

By the way, the most important thing is, you have to call the function on `mounted()` method, not on `created()`